# How to include CACert.pem with VS2015 curl project so that there is no need to specify CAINFO curl option?

Tags: c++, curl, visual-studio-2015, libcurl, pem

To set CAINFO option on CURL* currently I am including the CACert.pem file downloaded from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem with the binary.

Is there a way to have that file included within project so that its within binary and there is no need to explicitly specify CAINFO option?
I believe there is some way, because the same calls without setting CAINFO work on OSX where I am using system curl library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends!

libcurl itself can get built to use a large number of different TLS libraries and they all have their own little differences. The devil is really in the details as usual.

### mac

The "native" libcurl on macOS is built to use the internal "secure transport" TLS library and by default it uses the internal "trust store" that Apple ships. Most applications thus won't need to provide any CA certs.

Many people are however opting to use their own custom build on mac as well and then it may use nother TLS library (mostly done since the native mac one is fairly limited in functionality).

### windows

Similarly, libcurl on windows built to use schannel (the native windows TLS solution) can use the Windows internal trust store.

A libcurl on Windows that is built to use OpenSSL, however - which is the most popular TLS library choice - needs a separate and provided trust store to use, since it won't use the default one. You can then provide that trust store *either* as a separate file to pass to libcurl **or** you set it using the [CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION.html) callback as show in the [cacertinmem example](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/cacertinmem.html) from the curl web site.

Comment: Thanks for explaination. Does it make any difference setting CA_INFO or using SSL_CTX_FUNCTION, apart from that the certificate is hidden from user in latter case?

Comment: There's no technical difference in functionality, no. But if your program lives a long time you may want to be able to update the trust store...